# SharePoint Page URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, master-page, pages

I have created an SPFx web part and added it to an page (eg. "abc.aspx") in SharePoint. Then I made this page as an welcome page for my SharePoint site.

Now the URL of the welcome page is:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Sitename/pages/abc.aspx
```

How can I make it to:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Sitename
```

Comment: Is this classic experience or modern experience? If you have made any page as a "Home page" & you hit the URL (`https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Sitename`), it should automatically redirect you to correct page.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, It is redirecting me to the correct URL. ie. https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Sitename/pages/abc.aspx. but I want to make it short - ie. https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Sitename. I see in other sites of my organization where the welcome page is an custom page in - /sitename/pages folder but still the URL remains short as https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Sitename.